# Ubuntu Server 15.04 how to login using ssh?

Tags: server, ssh, 15.04

After installation, I tried to login from a remote computer using ssh. It asks for the password but it does not allow the server password as valid. What is the default configuration for ssh in Ubuntu Server? How to change the password (without changing the password for root)?

Comment: Can you paste the entire connection line that you are using form your terminal and include verbose output. For example `ssh -vvv user@ipaddress`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disable the password access and used private/public key. Follow this document:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

Note! Generates the keys in your client computer and transfer the public key to the server! Do not disable the passwords authentication until you test login using the public key.

Answer (score 0):

Often the default ssh config doesn't allow root login, or root login with a password (i.e. you have to use an ssh key). You could change this, but you're probably better off ssh-ing in as a normal user and using sudo or su, unless you have special requirements for some reason.